# Unable to resume activity runtime exception

Tags: java, android

Any ideas what is this error and what else do u want me to upload to help solve this problem.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code/com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code.single_player}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3493)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3533)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1584)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:347)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4557)
at com.wolframite.manos.crack_the_code.single_player.onResume(single_player.java:736)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1270)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6960)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3470)
... 8 more
```

Comment: Are you trying to display a number in a TextView? Convert it to a String first.

Comment: Please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set Integer values in `setText(String)` method,

Try converting `Integer` to `String` using..(In `onResume()` of your Activity)

```
setText(Integer.toString(intValue))
```

Comment: Care to explain where in the log did you see this error, since there is no code?

Comment: What do you mean 'the available detail'. I'm only asking where did you see the parsing exception?

Comment: @buzzingsilently you maybe disturb the problem resolution and cause the distancing from core issue. But it resolved the problem. You had luck